# Spring Data JPA returns empty pageables

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am new to Spring JPA. I use Spring JPA for database access in a Spring Boot project but I have a problem.

I use pageable requests through a JPARepository. I have created a method to enable pageable requests in the repository:

```
    @Query("select d from Document d where d.type=:type")
    Page<Document> findByType(String type, Pageable pageable);
```

I call the method and process the data in a loop. When the data in the page has been processed I do a check to see if there are more pages with data to process by acquiring a new pageable from the Page like so:

```
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, 1000, Sort.by("name"));

while (pageable != null) {
    Page<Dokument> xmlDocuments = documentRepository.findByType("XML", pageable);
    
    //process data

    if (xmlDocuments.hasNext()) {
        pageable = xmlDocuments.nextPageable();
    } else {
        pageable = null;
    }
}
```

The problem is that even though the Page states that there are 100 pages in total containing data only 50 of them actually contains data. The other 50 are empty. And after processing all 100 pages I can see that only 50% of the entries in the database have been processed.

I have been unable to locate the problem and I was hoping someone here might be able to.

Comment: You are processing things, which changes state, the state changes changes the results of the query. So you are probably changing the column(s) that are also part of the `where` part of the query. Hence skipping a page each time.

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you very much for your help.